# How to add a file to a self-extracting RAR archive?

Tags: winrar

Is there a way to automatically add a file to an existing SFX archive?

I have created with **WinRAR** the self-extracting archive `Test.exe`.

Now I want to add `C:\test\Test.txt` to `Test.exe`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i found out the following command line arg to do the trick.

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -ep C:\test\test.exe c:\test\test.txt
```

- `-ep` is a switch to ignore the path, which i wanted
- `a` is to add.

more help is there if you run rar or winrar from command prompt.

Comment: You might consider using -cfg- switch in order to avoid WinRAR's default settings dependency. Otherwise, WinRAR default settings might override your -zOptions.txt file content. Cheers!